# CSS padding for single TD inside a table

Tags: html, html-table, padding

I have a table, constructed like this:

```
<table>
<tr>  <td>1</td>  <td>2</td>  <td rowspan="4">3</td></tr>
<tr>  <td>4</td>  <td>5</td>                        </tr>
<tr>  <td>6</td>  <td>7</td>                        </tr>
<tr>  <td>8</td>  <td>9</td>                        </tr>
<tr height="100"><td colspan="2">10</td><td class="eleven">11</td> </tr>
</table>
```

Now the problem is within the last row. Whole row has a height set to 100px, so there is a plenty of room in TDs. In the very last TD I want to set an individual padding, so only the content "11" is padded from the top:

```
.eleven {
    padding-top:15px;
}
```

Setting this causes the problem - the first TD in this row also gets padding-top:10px; Why and how to make only the 2nd one padded?

Comment: your code seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/rdQvZ/. what is the problem??

Comment: you might want to check back your css,your other css codes .the table and the .eleven css is ok

Comment: You should create a jsFiddle illustrating your problem. Maybe also specify which browser you are experiencing these problems in?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I found out what caused the problem. It was an entry in a little html5-css-reset snippet I use:

```
vertical-align:baseline;
```

assigned generally to most of common elements. Having that in mind, now everything works as supposed to.

Answer (score 10):

Why don't you wrap the content you want to be padded into a `<div>` (onto which you will be applying the padding style) and put that `<div>` into the `<td>`?

```
<td>
    <div style="padding-top: 15px;"> 
        Content 
    </div> 
</td>
```

Comment: Because you don't place extra divs where you don't need 'em, and definitely you don't apply inline styling for such divs.

Comment: You can place div's anywhere you need, its a "division". I just gave the inline styling option to keep things simple, to show him how it can be done with minimal code. Obviously he knows how to write style classes, he can figure out how to separate them. Div gives him a lot more flexibility in the future. What if he switches from a table based design to something else, the Div's can keep him safe.